# Integration over $S^2$ in electrostatics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential

I'm studying for a test in electrostatics and I'm always failing on putting up the correct integrals.

In one problem I have the surface of a sphere with radius $a$ and an opening angle of $2\theta$. There is a total charge $Q$ evenly distributed on the surface. I want to calculate the potential.

In order to calculate the potential I first have to calculate the surface charge distribution, $\sigma(r)$, and this is where I always fail. I've done like this:

$Q=\sigma A=\sigma 4\pi r^2$

Then I tried to convert this into spherical coordinates by changing $r$ into $r=a \sin\theta \cos\phi +a \sin\theta \sin\phi +a \cos\theta$

The correct integral should be 
$Q=\sigma a^2\int_0^\theta \sin \theta d\theta \int_0^{2\pi}\!d\phi$

Can someone explain how to put up integrals like these?

Comment: What do you mean by opening angle?

Comment: If you have an entire sphere $S^2$ with charge distributed evenly, then your formula $Q=\sigma 4\pi r^2$ is correct. What's the problem?

Comment: I think we don't have a complete spherical surface area but just a part of it. The opening angle is the angle in the bottom of the "cone" that is created if we imagine lines from the edges of the spherical area to the origo of the sphere. The assignment is a little bit unclear though. 

Yes, I think my formula is correct but I want the answer in the form that contains integrals above ("the correct answer"), but I don't manage to do this. Perhaps I have just calculated something wrong?

Comment: @Djamillah, go to this wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system. you will get you answer there in "Integration and differentiation in spherical coordinates" section. Remember r is constant for you case and equal to a.

Comment: @JamalS, yeah he will get that there.

Comment: @Djamillah, are you sure the correct integral has this $\int_0^\theta$? I think it should be $\int_0^{\pi-\theta}$ or $\int_\theta^{\pi}$ if you take azimuthal symmetry to make your problem easier.

Comment: Yes I think so. There are two different $\theta$ one that's a variable and one that's just a non specified value on the variable $\theta$ (the opening angle). A little bit confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The induced metric on a sphere $S^2$ of radius $r$ is given by,

$$\mathrm{d}s^2 = g_{\mu\nu}\mathrm{d}x^\mu \mathrm{d}x^\nu = r^2\mathrm{d}\theta^2 + r^2 \sin^2 \theta \, \mathrm{d}\phi^2$$

We find $\sqrt{g}=r^2 \sin \theta$, and the surface area must be given by the integral,

$$A = \int_{S^2} \mathrm{d}^2 x \, \sqrt{g}= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \! \! \mathrm{d}\phi  \int_0^\pi \! \mathrm{d}\theta \, (r^2 \sin \theta)=4\pi r^2$$

If a net charge $Q$ is distributed evenly on the surface of a sphere, the charge density is,

$$\sigma = \frac{Q}{A} = \frac{Q}{4\pi r^2}$$

The integral provided in the question is also an integration over a sphere of radius $a$, but in more generality for any angle $\theta$; we chose $\theta=\pi$ to integrate over all of $S^2$. Otherwise, the integral is nothing more than that.

---

**Addendum: Induced Metric**

How did we find $g_{\mu\nu}$? The embedding of a sphere $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is given by,

$$X^\mu =\left(r\cos\theta\sin\phi, r\sin\theta\sin\phi, r\cos\phi\right)$$

The induced metric is given by the pullback of $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto the sphere,

$$g_{ab}=\frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial \sigma^a} \frac{\partial X^\nu}{\partial \sigma^b}\delta_{\mu\nu} $$

as $\delta_{\mu\nu} = \mathrm{diag}(1,1,1)$  is the metric of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The embedding itself is a solution to,

$$x^2 +y^2 +z^2 = r^2$$

which is the standard equation of a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ centered at the origin.